# What materials can I use to make a cast for melting lead?

Tags: metalworking, mold-making, casting

What materials can I use to make a cast for melting lead?
And how would I make the cast?

Comment: For small casts, cuttlebone used to be fashionable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuttlebone

Answer (score 4):

**Most household pans work fine for melting lead**. Make sure they are thick enough, don't have plastic parts, and don't have Teflon or similar coatings (Teflon and lead share their melting points, [apparently](https://www.protolabs.com/media/1014742/teflon.pdf)). It's best to use a metal handle (I've used those aluminum camping pan grippers in the past, which are very practical, but I only melted relatively small batches).
Cast iron and steel pans and pots are all okay.
The **Dutch oven** and a cut-in-half propane tank seem to be fan favourites for melting lead.

Lead melts at the relatively low 327°C (621°F). High heat settings on stoves [can reach up to 343°C (650°F)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/85647). This means all household pans should be up to the task.

**You can use aluminum bakeware for casts** (like muffin pans, or those disposable oven dishes which can be shaped easily by hand if you don't care too much for detail).

You're probably aware of this, but **please be careful when melting lead**: the toxic gases can lead (heh) to lead poisoning. Preferably work outside and definitely [use a respirator](https://pksafety.com/blog/lead-dust-and-fume-protection-for-fishermen-melting-lead) (rated N-100, R-100, or P-100/HEPA; and opt for a reusable one ('half face') as they have superior face seal), eye protection, and protective clothing (in case of splashes).

Comment: Excellent answer. I suggest mentioning and clarifying a couple of points: 1) Can you use a pan with a nonstick coating? 2) I assume (but would like to see it confirmed or not) that a pan used for melting lead should not be later returned to use for cooking food.

Comment: @csk Added, thank you. As for #2, I simply wouldn't risk it (see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/castiron/comments/6asuwc/if_a_ci_skillet_was_used_to_melt_lead_will_it/) for comments :).

Comment: You can often pick up stainless steel pans cheap second hand in charity shops (and presumably thrift stores in other countries).  That would seem a reasonable way to get a dedicated pan

Answer (score 2):

By "cast," think they are trying to say mold. The beginning technology would be silica sand with a binder. Silica is common beige beach or "play" sand; the binder could be water (damp sand), but will have no strength when it dries. I am thinking something like white wood glue diluted with water. Or, look up "how to make a simple sand mold" on the net. As answered, any kitchen pan could work, but I would not use aluminum because its strength is seriously compromised before 650 F. Industrial lead pots are cast iron (no coatings); I think that is a good hint. Although more expensive, I suggest pewter (mostly tin) or a solder like 50/50 lead/tin for beginning efforts. This is not rocket science; before video games, most kids I knew melted lead toy soldiers for something or other using a kitchen pan.

Comment: There are internet sites for "sand casting pewter" that give more info. Just replace "pewter" with lead and you will need about 100 f higher temperatures but everything is very similar.